# Map multiple domains to subfolders in EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, subdomain

I have an ec2 instance running a LAMP stack. I plan on hosting some client mockups, static sites, etc. what i want to achieve is havethe sites in `/var/www/sites/site1`, `/var/www/sites/site2` and so on. then mapping a url to each so it will end up like `example.com` mapping to `/var/www/sites/site1`. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easily with AWS:

1. Set up virtual hosts on your EC2 instance for each of your client web projects. If you are using Apache for example, each vhost configuration basically just tells Apache what the domain will be, where the files live and which ports to listen on.
2. Your EC2 instance will need a public IP or an elastic IP if you aren't using a load balancer setup.
3. Set up your Route 53 records. These are DNS records which will tell Amazon to route traffic for certain sub domains under your domain (a "hosted zone") to wherever you specify. If you are using a load balancer then you can create an alias (A record) directly to the public DNS of the elastic load balancer. If you are just using EC2 then use your public IP of the EC2 instance as the target, and create an Alias record to it for each domain or sub domain.

You can test the EC2 component by spoofing from your local computers hosts file to each target domain by using the instance's public IP address underneath the domain name for it. When you are happy you can switch off the spoofing and test the actual DNS routing from Route 53.

I have done this plenty of times with 20-30 applications running through a single instance. If you need any help with parts of this, please ask.